# Hidden files in Disk Usage Analyzer

Tags: linux, disk-space

How do I get Ubuntu's "Disk Usage Analyzer" to show me the hidden files?

It tells me my home dir uses 3GB, but only accounts for 525MB (the results of `du -shc *`).  Can I get it to show me the other files that are using the space?

Comment: `du` already shows all files, it doesn't hide anything. What exactly are the 3GB and 525MB figures reported for?

Comment: You should try 'ncdu' which is generally available in your distro's repositories, its text interface is great.

Comment: You may also need to run as root, and not with sudo but with actual root, via su root.

Answer (score 20):

You can use this (it does not match files with a single letter after the '.')

```
du -shc .??* *
```

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_%28Unix%29) also mentions a regex style usage which should work for every file/folder name

```
du -shc .[!.]* *
```

Comment: Why two *'s? I.e. why `.??* *` and not just `.??*`. They seem to do the same thing. And what syntax accounts for `* *` anyway?

Comment: `du -shc .??* *` includes both hidden (`.??*`) and visible (`*`) files/folders, while `du -shc .??*` shows only the hidden ones. We are essentially passing two patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Call `du` with the whole home directory rather than every single file:

```
du -sh ~
```

That's because the `*` doesn't match the hidden ones.

Comment: This does not list all the files in `~`.

Comment: @lindhe care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. It displays the aggregate size of all files (both plain and hidden) in `~`. It does not however list the size of each file and subdirectory in `~`. I assumed that was what OP wanted, since `du -sch *` would do that (but only for plain files).

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem today. My solution:

```
du -h | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) {print $1"/"$2}}'
```

`du -h` gives us the complete usage of current directory including all subdirectories recursively.

`| awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) {print $1"/"$2}}'` filters the output and prints no subdirectories.

If you want to see the files in addition to the directories you can use this:

```
du -ah | awk -F/ '{if (NF<3) {print $1"/"$2}}'
```

If you want to see exactly which files use the most disk space you can add `| sort -h` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "find" + "du" to see the hidden files and folders:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -exec du -hs {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
du -shc *
```

it excludes everything that starts with a dot.

Try:

```
du -shc ~
```

instead

Comment: One of the common culprits for chewing space under your home dir is `.TRASH`, the default trash directory used by distributions like Ubuntu.

Comment: Strangely, this shows 150GB (which I think is the total of all my filesystem usage) - and none of the sub-directories or files.  Pretty useless really

Comment: @Stephen: you may have symlinks that are throwing things off. Try adding the `-D` option.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities for unaccounted for space (other than the very valid point about . files and * expansion others suggested) include the 5% of the disk that is occasionally reserved for root (relatively common) and files hidden underneath a mount point.

For that last, imagine you have a folder /tmp/somerandom/raccoon/.  In this folder you put 2.5G of video.  You then mount your USB disk on /tmp/somerandom/.  You can no longer access the file/files that you put in /tmp/somerandom/raccoon, but they still take up disk space.  du doesn't see them, but df does.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Usage Analyzer does not show files (as I would expect) - if the % below a certain directory don't show up, then open the folder and look at the files individually.