# Low disk space shows in Ubuntu inside VmWare

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, vmware, ubuntu-20.04

I have a vmware and inside that I have installed ubuntu 20.04. Initially I have assigned 180GB for the VM disk space. But inside my ubuntu OS, I am getting an error saying low disk space. I am pretty sure I dont have anything upto 180GB. Below are some images of the command `df -h` and from the application "Disk Usage Analyzer" in ubuntu.

[image: df -h]

[image: Disk Usage Analyzer]

[image]

I have assigned 16GB of Ram for this Vm and I have no idea how or why this showing as low space. To be honest if I calculate all the space that I have used itll be around 20GB or 25GB out of 180GB.

Comment: Try shrinking the machine. There may be space used from old updates.   sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /

Comment: Do I need to do anything like taking backup before doing this? @John

Comment: It is always worth having a backup. Always. But I shrink Ubuntu and Kali machines this way and do not have any issue.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it shows 26GB when I go inside my drive from Disk Usage Analyzer?

Comment: I cannot readily answer that.

Comment: Shrinking the VM will decrease the size of the virtual disks on the *host*; it will *not* help in this case.  This isn't a VM issue; it's an issue with the guest.  Clearly `df` thinks that `/dev/sda5` is consuming 167GB.  Also, it seems like you ran the disk usage analyzer as yourself (and not as a superuser), so it can't report sizes for directories it can't access (such as `lost+found` and `root`).  Try running it as a superuser and see if it reports anything different.  It also seems that the [disk usage analyzer doesn't report hidden files](https://superuser.com/questions/177669/).

Comment: Running disk usage analyzer as root showed me what ate my disk space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Large Files Consuming Space

This could be a problem with large file(s) hogging up space on the virtual machine. In this case, it is beneficial to [check disk usage](https://superuser.com/questions/190627/ubuntu-10-04-recurring-low-disk-space-issues?rq=1) with either `du` or the disk usage analyzer.

It may be useful to launch the disk usage analyzer as `su` to see all directories by running `sudo baobab`.

[image]

### Incorrect Disk Partitioning

This could also be a problem that the VMware Host has allocated disk space that is not recognized by the Guest Ubuntu OS.

The command `lsblk` will show the size of the partitions. Here, the VMware Host thinks it has 80GB in `sda`, but the Ubuntu OS is only using 20GB on `sda5`.

[image]

In this case, it is possible to [extend the partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417938/ubuntu-does-not-use-full-disk-space-how-to-extend) to take advantage of the unallocated space. The tool `gparted` can be used to view and resize the partitions:

1. `sudo apt-install gparted`
2. `sudo gparted`
3. right click on the partition and adjust to the new size
4. accept the changes

**Note:** the below photo is from *after* resizing the partition as I did not take a before screenshot.

[image]

After resizing, the portion should occupy the desired space.

[image]